# Who is the "Motherless bastard" that Petyr Baelish is talking about in S06E10?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

In the episode 6x10 of GOT, Littlefinger speaks with Sansa

> after they defeated the Boltons

He talks about his dream and they talk about who should lead the North. There Littlefinger has a line:

> A trueborn daughter of Ned and Catelyn Stark born here at Winterfell or a motherless bastard born in the south?

Who does he speak of? In the context he could only mean Jon, because it's either him or Sansa who takes command.

> But he talks about a motherless bastard from the south. Could Littlefinger know that Jon is the son of Rhaegar or did he only mean that he was born in the south, assuming that he is the child of Ned and that motherless means that no one knows who Jon's mother is?

Am I just over-interpreting things here, or does he speak of someone completely different?

Comment: Nobody knows (as far as we're aware) that Jon is a Targaryen. As far as the world is aware he's Ned Stark's bastard by some unknown woman. Either way he's a motherless bastard from the south.

Comment: @Moogle there is one who knows. http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Howland_Reed

Comment: @kuhl good point, I'd forgotten about Howland Reed. I guess news could have spread from him, but he's a very secretive person who was a good friend of Ned's, and fiercely loyal, so I doubt he would have told anyone.

Comment: @kuhl: more than one, there was a nurse present:  http://preview.tinyurl.com/zhxsgu6

Comment: I'm struggling to understand how this question can be considered a dupe.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

He is talking about Jon.

Jon was born somewhere in South (We know it is Dorne but most people do not).

Eddard Stark went to war against King Aerys Targaryen with Robert Baratheon, Jon Arryn and Hoster Tully. The war was fought in South. When Eddard came back from war, he had Jon with him which made it clear for every one that Jon was born in South.

Jon is a bastard whose mother is unknown to most people. Therefore, Jon is the motherless bastard born in South while Sansa is the trueborn daughter born in Winterfell.

Also, Littlefinger could not possibly know about true parentage of Jon. Only two people knew of it; Lord Howland Reed and Lord Eddard Stark. And Eddard had openly declared Jon to be his son in front of the whole realm so that's what Littlefinger knows as well. This is proved by Baelish's conversation with Sansa in S06E05:

> Baelish: The time may come when you need an army loyal to you.
>
> Sansa: I have an army.
>
> Baelish: **Your brother's army. Half-brother.**

So it is proven that Baelish thinks Jon is Sansa's half brother.

This "born in south" dialogue is an absurd innovation of show. Robb Stark was also born in Riverrun which is situated in South, not North.

Comment: “This "born in south" dialogue is an absurd innovation of show.” Absurd! Jon was born in the South, and Littlefinger says he was born in the South! What *are* those crazy writers thinking?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite It is absurd because those writers make it sound like it is a bad thing. What makes it absurd is, Robb Stark was also born in South. And he is now a legendary KiTN. Which proves that being born in South does not have any impact on someone's popularity in North.

Comment: I think Littlefinger is trying to make it sound like a bad thing, to Sansa. He’s not above confidently talking nonsense in an attempt to further his interests.

Comment: @Paul Yeah and Robb wasn't up for "election" against someone born in Winterfell itself. Jon is (hypothetically). That's the point. In this case Littlefinger is comparing apples and oranges, whereas a few years ago actually there were only apples so it really didn't matter.

Comment: When Catelyn married Ned, she gave up her southern life to become a Stark of the North.  The mother of the Jon Stark, according to the story Ned was pushing, was and remained Southern.  So, yeah, Robb was technically born in the South, but I think the connotation of a legitimate birth that happened to be while out of town to "true" northerners would be different. Littlefinger is trying to spin it as much as possible. We're in the middle of political silly season here in the USA, people are believing much more illogical stuff than that. Doesn't seem to be that much of a stretch, dialogue-wise.

Comment: @AndrewMattson Catelyn did not become Northern. She still worshipped the new gods of the South. Ned even built a sept for her in Winterfell. She never liked spending time in Godswood. It was Ned she loved and Ned due to whom she adapted to North. Though I would not go as far as suggesting that she became Northern, there is simply no evidence for that. Paul's explanation is most plausible, he was just trying to make Sansa feel that Jon isn't Northern enough.

Comment: "Only two people knew of it; Lord Howland Reed and Lord Eddard Stark." --false; remember there is a nurse present: http://preview.tinyurl.com/zhxsgu6

Comment: @JeromyFrench Actually there were two dornish girls there, not one and we do not know if they were "nurses" or just maids/midwives. Anyways, regarding those girls, see my previous answer [here](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/133161/is-there-any-tangible-proof-of-jon-snows-lineage/133164#133164)

Comment: " What are those crazy writers thinking?" They're thinking that watchers of the show (as opposed to readers of the books) will prefer as strong a dichotomy between the North and South as possible. He wants to portray Sansa as "legitimate" in the sense of being completely, authentically of the North, and to cast any aspersions he can on Jon Snow. The show does not refer to Robb's place of birth, and Sansa does not bring it up.

Answer (score -4):

He could be talking about Gendry, or one of Robert's other bastards.

The King in the North is not the ruler unless independence becomes real. If one of Robert's children take the throne in the South and manage to unify the land, then they would also rule the North.

Comment: Gendry is an unacknowledged bastard. Nobody knows he is Robert's son. None of Robert's bastards were acknowledged (in the show). Therefore they have just as much chance of winning the throne as Hot pie does. Also they do not fit in the context.

Comment: @Aegon Fair enough about the context, but the first part clearly isn't true, since they were trying to kill Gendry in season 1.

Comment: In Books Cersei gave the order to kill the bastards because they were living proof that Joff, Myrcella and Tommen were not Robert's children. In show I believe Joff gave the order for the same reason or just cruelty. They never gave the order because Gendry had a claim to throne. Only a handful of people knew Gendry was Robert's son. Most of them are dead, only Cersei and Melisandre are alive.

Comment: It's not impossible that Littlefinger knows about Gendry but Sansa certainly doesn't.

Comment: Why would Littlefinger be talking to Sansa about Gendry?

Comment: @TheMathemagician It is possible that Little Finger knows about Gendry because (at least in books), When asked by Eddard about bastards of Robert, Baelish replied that Robert had more bastards than Eddard did which means he knew about some bastards at least. But it won't help Gendry because Gendry's power would come only from Stormlands and Stormlords do not know and will not believe without any proof.

Comment: @Aegon to be fair, everyone was Robert's bastard in the book.

Comment: @CaptainMan Lol that would be more true about Aegon IV if we are talking about books. Maynard Plumm said so as well