# What are counterarguments to R+L=J?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire, jon-snow

I know that there is [at least one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6974/what-evidence-is-there-supporting-an-alternative-parentage-for-jon-snow) question on here about the theory of R+L=J, but there ought to be a question on here for the arguments against. (Spoilers all, to be safe)

What evidence from ASOIAF suggests that Rhaegar and Lyanna are not the parents of Jon Snow?

Comment: @Mooz, I appreciate the spirit of your edit, but I'm not sure why you included a written spoiler warning and then bolded the part you deemed the actual spoiler - making it more visible - rather than using spoiler tags.

Comment: The bolding just illustrates to people the actual question being asked. I felt that a general spoiler warning and then no spoiler tag was sufficient in this case. (I personally feel that the question doesn't *look* as nice if it's in a spoiler tag) :)

Comment: Well, I guess they may not be aesthetically pleasing to all :). Personally, I don't find written spoiler warnings very helpful; especially on a question as small as this where the spoiler in question is but three lines from the warning, my eyes can too easily flick down and process the spoiler without meaning to.

Comment: This question is really a re-statement of the one you link and so they should have the same answers.

Comment: They just had an article where martin says that some of the biggest theories out there are actually right, and he considered changing the story to throw people off, but its too late. Alot of people assumed that this was in reference to R + L = J since it is the biggest and most talked about theory.

Comment: I would be surprised, @Himarm. It sounded like he was talking about a very select minority of readers; R+L=J is **very** popular, to the point where it seems commonplace on forum posts to write, without argument, "Assuming R+L=J". It almost seems like it's too right to be true.

Comment: this is the article i read, its still all speculation, but alot of people feel this is what he was referring too. [Here](http://www.vanityfair.com/vf-hollywood/2014/08/game-of-thrones-george-rr-martin-readers-have-predicted-ending)

Comment: It's a broken link. I read a similar article on another website, though.

Comment: Not an arguement, but technically, by the time frames, Arthur Dayne could have been the father.

Answer (score 2):

It is generally hard to prove a negative. AFAIK, there is no way to completely rule out R+L=J. The only recourse is to look at arguments supporting the claim that Ned Stark is indeed Jon's father.  And those arguments have been summarized in the question you've cited:

> Reasons to affirm that Eddard is Jon's father:
>
> In the aforementioned investigation by Catelyn, a recurring rumor was that the mother was Ashara Dayne. It is implied by other
>   flashbacks (principally the story of the Knight of the Laughing Tree)
>   that Ashara and Eddard shared a mutual attraction.
>
> When pressed by Robert, Eddard claims the mother is a servant girl named Wylla. Edric Dayne claims to Arya Stark that Wylla was his wet
>   nurse (making him Jon's milk brother), giving more credence to the
>   story, and that Wylla was not just a name Eddard made up to shut
>   people up.

Comment: Having only seen the first series, R+L=J seems to require Ned to lie to his wife too, for no compelling reason. He trusts her with pretty much everything else. Also, nothing requires Ned to claim parentage - he could raise the kid with his sons like that hostage fellow and it would be even less visible to others than John Snow is. What Ned did is inferior tactically to these other options, so the  explanation is that it is true.

Comment: @Oldcat - the obvious family likeness (Jon's likeness to Arya is noted on a number of occasions in the books) is a giveaway that Jon has Stark blood.  Also, keeping his promise to his sister is compelling reason enough: Ned is stubborn like that.  Finally, the key quote in the book is that Jon is his blood (point 2 in the accepted answer to the other question); Ned didn't necessarily lie, Catelyn may have just put 2 and 2 together and got 47.

Comment: @DarthSatan Jon looks like Arya, who is also often compared to Ned's sister, Lyanna!

Comment: @Mooz - exactly.  Ned had to tell *some* story otherwise people would start asking questions.  Awkward questions.

Comment: @Oldcat - You have to remember that Ned and Cat weren't always this close to each other. He only married her out of duty to his House, when he in fact he loved someone else (according to popular theory anyway).

Comment: @DarthSatan - ok, if he had to claim Snow as a Stark, then why not let your wife in on it. Now, nobody knows the secret and he can't keep his promise to his sister.

Comment: @Oldcat - don't know, other than that it seems very much in-character for Ned to be stubborn about this.