# When was R+L=J first publicly mentioned?

Tags: a-song-of-ice-and-fire

I am re-reading the Song of Ice and Fire series and pay special attention to all the hints and clues in the background. There is a popular fan theory

> that Jon Snow is actually the son of Rhaegar Targaryen and Lyanna
>  Stark. This was confirmed in the TV show but remains to be confirmed
>  in the books

When was this formulated (publicly) for the first time? I would like to see what the first hints or arguments were for why this should be true.

Comment: Related:  https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6974/what-evidence-is-there-supporting-an-alternative-parentage-for-jon-snow/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is tough to nail a "public" first.  In the earlier days of the series and the internet George did a lot fan engagement through letters, emails, and online chats. Fans were speculating on Jon's parentage from the very beginning as clues and hints were being dropped almost from the start.

**Early speculation has been documented in July 1999.**

I am not 100% sure if this was the first time it was brought up, but a letter from a fan was asking about Jon's day of birth in relation to Daenerys'. It seems the writer was trying to determine if R+L=J was true or at least maybe ruling out that N+A=J.

> [letter author] *I'm trying to figure out how Jon's day of birth fits in the timeline of the war, and assumed you wouldn't just tell me when he was exactly born.:-)*
>
> ...
>
> *I will spare you the rest of my speculations about the date of Jon's birth, since their only real conclusion is that Catelyn seems a little thick when she thinks that Ned fathered Jon as he returned 'Dawn' to Ashara Dayne.*
>
> [GRRM] Ah... I see what you're driving at here, I guess...
>
> ...
>
> As to your speculations about Catelyn and Ashara Dayne... sigh... needless to say, All Will Be Revealed in Good Time. I will give you this much, however; Ashara Dayne was not nailed to the floor in Starfall, as some of the fans who write me seem to assume. They have horses in Dorne too, you know. And boats (though not many of their own). As a matter of fact (a tiny tidbit from SOS), she was one of Princess Elia's lady companions in King's Landing, in the first few years after Elia married Rhaegar.
>
> The rest I will save for the books.
>
> <sub>[So Spake Martin, Entry 1040, Chronology](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1040)</sub>

**In an online chat in September 2000 the direct question of "who is Jon's mother" was asked.**

> Tigers14: another question, can NW vows be annulled if a person had no idea who he really was when he took them?
>
> GeoRR: who had no idea who he was?
>
> Tigers14: jon
>
> GeoRR: Jon knows who he is. He may not know who his mother is, but that's not the same thing. There are plenty of orphans and bastards in the Watch who don't know who their parents are.
>
> Tigers14: yes. but if jon is the legitimate son of rhaegar and lyanna , he is the king of westeros.
>
> GeoRR: well, you know I am not going to get into any of that
>
> GeoRR: I think I've said enough for tonight.
>
> <sub>[So Spake Martin, Entry 1128, Minisa Tully and Sansa](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1128)</sub>

So for a chat that was not one-on-one we have this:

> Moderator: do we ever get to know the answers for the questions left open-ended in the first three books?
> GRRM: But I have read much historical fiction about the Crusades.
>
> Moderator: because we REALLY want to know who is jon's mother
>
> GRRM: Most of the questions will be answered by the end, yes.
>
> GRRM: Some may be answered subtly, however.
>
> Moderator: but not all?
>
> Moderator: oh, so we will have to debate that then!
>
> GRRM: Well, "all" is a big word... my fans are always asking new questions.
>
> GRRM: Jon's history will be revealed, yes.
>
> <sub>[So Spake Martin, Entry 1324, Opus Press Chat](https://www.westeros.org/Citadel/SSM/Entry/1324)</sub>